# Python handle versions of the same external package over different internal packages

Tags: python, pip, package, python-packaging

For example we have three internal packages called: A, B, and C. All these three packages use requests. But package A has requests `~=2.4.0` in the requirements, B has `~=2.6.0` and C has `~=2.9.0`.

The problem is when we have a project which installs all three internal packages A, B and C. This will give a warning or error during installation with pip since it cannot resolve to the current version of requests.

We always try to use `~=` in our requirements as we want a compatible version.

So the question is in a broader sense, what is the best way to handle requirements between different internal packages which use the same external package?

The only solution now is that we upgrade all the packages at the same time, but is becoming undoable.

Comment: On one hand this question seems to say that requirements are pinned, and on the other hand it mentions `~=`, so it is a bit confusing to me. Can the question be clarified, maybe with a more concrete example?

Comment: I made an edit, hope this clarifies. @sinoroc

Comment: Edit your question to show which version of pip and Python are you using? I do not see any reason why pip would have an issue solving this.